# How I can add column to matrix in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I want to add column of ones to 5x5 matrix on at 0 index. np.append() is working but i search another way.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(range(25)).reshape(5,5)
ones = np.ones((arr.shape[0],1))
arr_with_ones = np.append(ones, arr, axis=1)
print(arr_with_ones)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not need to predefine a `ones` array. You can use `numpy.insert` function directly:

```
arr = np.array(range(25)).reshape(5,5)
arr_with_ones = np.insert(arr, 0, 1, axis=1)
```

`np.insert(arr, 0, 1, axis=1)` inserts `value=1` in index `0` along `axis=1`(which is columns in 2D array) of array `arr`.

output:

```
[[ 1  0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 1  5  6  7  8  9]
 [ 1 10 11 12 13 14]
 [ 1 15 16 17 18 19]
 [ 1 20 21 22 23 24]]
```

Answer (score 0):

U Can try like this：

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(range(25)).reshape(5,5)
ones = np.ones((arr.shape[0],1))
arr_with_ones = np.c_[ones, arr]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `np.hstack((ones,arr))`   function as well.